# yaml workflow missing start tag

Tags: go, camunda, zeebe

I'm trying to use Go client to programmatically manage workflows. I'm using yaml, this is my workflow:

```
name: order-process
tasks:
    - id: collect-money
      type: payment-service

    - id: fetch-items
      type: inventory-service
      switch:
          - case: totalPrice > 100
            goto: ship-parcel-with-insurance     
          - default: ship-parcel

    - id: ship-parcel-with-insurance
      type: shipment-service-premium
      end: true

    - id: ship-parcel
      type: shipment-service
```

And when I deploy this, I can't visualize it in camunda operate, the page is stuck  on loading 
and I have this error in console:

```
Error: unparsable content detected
    line: 0
    column: 0
    nested error: missing start tag
```

Comment: I assume if you want to have the visual component as well then you should model your process model via the Zeebe Modeler

Comment: I kinda need to use the yaml format, it doesn't matter if I didn't have the visual component as long as I have a way to debug. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are parsing this ?

Comment: I'm using [camunda operate](https://github.com/zeebe-io/docker-camunda-operate) The unparsable error comes when I load the yaml in the camunda operate web UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we are sorry but Operate only supports BPMN XML deployments at the moment. The YAML support in Zeebe is only rudimentary and not intended for real-world use cases. It becomes really hard to model complex processes with yaml, which is easily possible with BPMN. We highly encourage you to switch to the [Zeebe Modeler](https://github.com/zeebe-io/zeebe-modeler/releases) to create your workflow models.

If you want to discuss this further, we are happy to welcome you in one of our [community channels](https://zeebe.io/community/).

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, but I'm mostly using this on headless servers and trying to use the Go client to generate workflows programmatically. I don't think there is a way to generate workflows programmatically with the Go client. Which is why I'm using some kind of hack to generate yaml workflows. You are right, yaml is very limited, I can do very little with it, compared to bpmn.